MudBlazor 7 issue with MudTreeView (
I recently upgraded to MudBazor v7 and have been working through the compilation issues.  This one's foxed me and I'm not sure how to fix.
<MudTreeView Items="TreeItems" MultiSelection="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <MudTreeViewItem Expanded="true" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context" Text="@context.Title" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudTreeView>

I get an error on the first line.  Looking at the example the only obvious thing is that I don't have an @ before "TreeItems".  Adding that doesn't change the error message.
The error I'm getting is:

CS0411    The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreateMudTreeView_1_CaptureParameters(IReadOnlyCollection<TreeItemData>, out IReadOnlyCollection<TreeItemData>, object, out object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

But I'm not sure how to fix this.
The property referenced by Items is:
protected HashSet<TerseTreeItemData>? TreeItems = null;

Where TerseTreeItemData is a simple class:
public class TerseTreeItemData
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = default!;
    public HashSet<TerseTreeItemData>? TreeItems { get; set; } = new();
}


You should use SelectionMode="SelectionMode.MultiSelection" instead of MultiSelection="true"

To enable multiselect, you need the code SelectionMode="SelectionMode.MultiSelection" @bind-SelectedValues="SelectedValues" and private IReadOnlyCollection<TerseTreeItemData>? SelectedValues { get; set; } after migration of MudBlazor7. https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/8661 Then the question would be the TreeItems type cannot be converted from HashSet to IReadOnlyCollection. Based on my research, it is not solved yet on complex T type.

Use the T="TerseTreeItemData" attribute in the MudTreeView to explicitly specify the type.
Alternatively you can use @ref as follows:
<MudTreeView @ref="@MyTree" Items="TreeItems" MultiSelection="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <MudTreeViewItem Expanded="true" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context" Text="@context.Title" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudTreeView>

@code{
   public MudTreeView<TerseTreeItemData> MyTree;
   protected HashSet<TerseTreeItemData>? TreeItems = null;
}

